# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anybody know why I have the error

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

When I try

> ALTER TABLE `hermanos`   ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_hno_provincia` FOREIGN KEY (`provincia`) REFERENCES `p_provincias` (`id`)

On these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hermanos` (
`codigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`apellidos` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`direccion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`codigoPostal` int(11) NOT NULL,
`provincia` int(11) NOT NULL,
`numeroHermano` int(11) NOT NULL,
`dni` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
`tipoCuota` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sexo` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`),
KEY `sexo` (`sexo`),
KEY `pk_hno_cuota` (`tipoCuota`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `p_provincias` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` varchar(125) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=53 ;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent and child tables must use the same storage engine.

I noticed that `hermanos` uses `InnoDB` and `p_provincias` uses `MyISAM`.

For more info, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> Foreign keys definitions are subject to the following conditions:
>
> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>   central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>   back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
>   table. **The parent and child tables must use the same storage engine.**
>   They must not be TEMPORARY tables.

Comment: Yep, I copied the table from the Internet and I didn't see the properties.. Thanks!

Comment: @JoseGonzalez Glad to be of help.